# Issues with migrating my app to iphone5 resolution

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to migrate my app for iphone 5. I have already seen the other questions in stackoverflow and still facing the some problems in correctly showing it.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        _backgroundimageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,500)];
        [_backgroundimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-568h@2x.png"]];
    } else {
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
        [_backgroundimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
    }
```

The size I have set for backgroundimageView is 320 x370 in the size inspector and the image size of image1-568h@2x.png has a size of 640x 1136 and of image1.png is 640x733.So, for 3.5 inch screen, it should show normally and for 4-inch screen, it should resize accordingly.

But the problem is that for 4-inch screen, it doesn't resize and ends up showing me the same   as 3inch screen with some white border to cover the remaining area.

Need some guidance to solve it. Thanks.. Can point out the mistake i am doing...

Comment: height is a float. 568 is an int. You might want to try `568.f`. Or `< 568`. What about landscape?

Comment: the code does go in there. I have set a breakpoint there... and it executes that line... no issue with that...

Comment: Ah ok. Could try `.autoresizingMask`, or auto layout if you can drop iOS 5 support. That should allow you to size it dynamically.

Comment: need ios5 support... so autoresizingMask?

Comment: Yeah, .autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth. You should be able to do this in interface builder if auto layout is turned off.

Comment: self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; i tried this now, not working either...

Comment: Are you initializing UIImageView in code, or interface builder? If IB, you should be able to do it there, with the auto layout box unchecked.

Comment: Perhaps some more info?  Have you tried an NSLog of the screen height?  Where and when is this code being called?

Comment: You should look at Madhu's answer again. I think you might be overwriting your existing backgroundimageView reference, which doesn't change the one you already have in the view hierarchy. Should do `backgroundimageView.frame = ` instead.

Comment: your backgroundimageView.frame worked.. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are again allocating `backgroundimageView` for iPhone 5 resolutions. Just use the same IBOutlet of `backgroundimageView` and modify the frame and image of it.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        _backgroundimageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
        [_backgroundimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-568h@2x.png"]];
    } else {
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
         _backgroundimageView.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,320,370);
        [_backgroundimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
    }
```

Comment: i dun understand you... but i need the frame for 3.5inch as well right?

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: On second thought, maybe you're right. It looks like he's overwriting backgroundimageView without addSubview.

Comment: Its strange.

 Just change the frame and image 


CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        _backgroundimageView.frame  = CGRectMake(0,0,320,500);
        [_backgroundimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-568h@2x.png"]];
    } else {
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
        _backgroundimageView.frame  = CGRectMake(0,0,320,x370);
        [_backgroundimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Default image name must be "Default-568h@2x.png" (not image1-568h@2x.png) try renaming the default image name and check again, you will get right screen size.

Also you can check iphone5 by macros.

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
```

Comment: i already have the default-568h@2x.png.. this is for the individual images i am using...

Answer (score 0):

I think content mode of your imageview is center so try this for your imageview

```
[_backgroundimageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]
```